# Referencing resources.resw in AppBar-Button

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need to reference a text from the resources.resw-file in a AppBar-Button, but as it is set as `AutomationProperties.Name=""`. 
I can not just  add it in the resources.resw as `AppBarSearch.AutomationProperties.Name`, so how can I reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutomationProperties.Name` is an attached property and you need to handle it [differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx), i.e. you need to include its namespace in the resource key:

```
AppBarSearch.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as I could not figure out how to get it work